# adding authentication to cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

[This](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/0.7/docs/configuration/authentication.html) blog explains how to add simple authentication to cassandra cluster. Essentially, we have to edit `cassandra.yaml` and few other files. It is not clear to me whether the changes have to be made in all of the nodes or making the changes in one of the nodes of the cluster would do?

It also appears that we need to have `Keyspaces` created before adding authentication to them. Is it not possible to give authentication to different users and then allow them to create their own `keyspaces`?

Answer (score 3):

To enable authentication in Cassandra, set the Password authenticator in cassandra.yaml file for all the Cassandra nodes. The Users who can connect to Cassandra can be created using CQL clients. Default userName and password is cassandra/cassandra. These user details are stored in system_auth keyspace. So increase the replication factor of the system_auth keyspace and follow the steps provided in the below link:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/security/security_config_native_authenticate_t.html

Creating user in any one node which will be reflected in all other nodes. You don't need to create in all the nodes.

Authentication does not restrict user in creating keyspace, but if you have enabled Authorization then you need to provide required access to the user in order to create keyspace, column_family(table), etc. in Cassandra as explained in the below link:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/security/secure_config_native_authorize_t.html